# Should Task-based WCF calls be OneWay?

Tags: c#, wcf, async-await

A WCF contract might look like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoSomethingFast();

    [OperationContract]
    void DoSomethingSlow();

    [OperationContract]
    int GetSomethingFast();

    [OperationContract]
    int GetSomethingSlow();
}
```

When a client makes any of these calls, its thread blocks while the server does its thing. For the `Fast` methods, that's no problem, but for the `Slow` methods, this blocking is far from ideal. We can add `(IsOneWay = true)` to the `DoSomething` methods, but we can't do the same for the `GetSomething` methods, because they really are two way - we *have* to wait for the result:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void DoSomethingFast();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void DoSomethingSlow();

    [OperationContract]
    int GetSomething();  

    [OperationContract]
    int GetSomethingSlow();    
}
```

Enter the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP). We define the contract to return `Task`, and WCF (to the best of my knowledge), does some magic behind the scenes and immediately returns a `Task` which waits for a callback from the WCF service before completing. This eliminates the client-side blocking, allowing the use of `await` instead:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    Task DoSomethingFastAsync();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    Task DoSomethingSlowAsync();

    [OperationContract]
    Task<int> GetSomethingAsync();  

    [OperationContract]
    Task<int> GetSomethingSlowAsync();    
}
```

My question is about how this all works, and whether you still need to include `(IsOneWay = true)` on the service contract:

- Is the *to the best of my knowledge* bit above accurate? Does WCF automatically return a `Task` which completes when the service tells us it's finished?
- Is `(IsOneWay = true)` necessary for the above magic to happen? If not, does it have any effect at all?
- Given that the callback from the service can be "I'm finished", or "Here's your result" with equal ease, can the `DoSomething` and `GetSomething` calls be treated equally? So if `(IsOneWay = true)` is necessary, can it also be used on the `GetSomething` methods?

Answer (score 0):

If the service is one way or not has nothing to do with the technology of the client. In C# method semantics, it just means that it's a `void` returning method.

Now, if the client is implemented in .NET and the user chooses to call it on a blocking way or not, it's her/his choice.

Before the introduction of [TAP (Task Asynchronous Patter)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh873175), there was [APM (Asynchronous Programming Model)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms228963) and [EAP (Event-based Asynchronous Pattern)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms228969) - if I recall correctly, WCF used EAP.